# Calculate the percentage for each target variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this,

```
category    target
A               1
B               1
A               0
A               0
A               0
B               0
C               1
C               1
```

I want to calculate the percentage of each target value in every category.
For example, the percentage for

'A'==1 is `count(1)/(count(1)+count(0))`,

'A'==0 is `count(0)/(count(1)+count(0))`

How can I get a table like this,

```
category        1          0
A              25%        75%
B              50%        50%
C             100%         0%
```

Maybe I should use some group-by functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with parameter `normalize='index'`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['category'], df['target'], normalize='index').mul(100)
print (df)
target       0      1
category             
A         75.0   25.0
B         50.0   50.0
C          0.0  100.0
```

Or use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
df = df.groupby('category').target.value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(fill_value=0).mul(100)
print (df)
target       0      1
category             
A         75.0   25.0
B         50.0   50.0
C          0.0  100.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have one more question. If the `target` also be a string type, or in pandas dataframe called `object`, will this method work, too?

Comment: @JiayuZhang - yop, because it count values.